# Is possible read objective-c code that is generated from Adobe Flash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, flash, adobe

I make an iPhone app with Flash and it generates my app and a xml (that I don't understand if is it useful). My question is if I can read the objective-c code that Flash generates.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  [According to Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html), Adobe Flash Professional CS5 builds its applications by using LLVM to compile ActionScript code and output the finished ARM binary.

No Objective-C code is generated as a result of this process.

Answer (score 5):

Flash does not generate Objective-C code.

Comment: Uhmmmm I don't think so. As you may be generated an iPhone app without going through objective-c or c any case?